# How to increase the number of threads for Rails using Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, capistrano3

I have a Ruby on Rails application that gets an extremely high volume of requests at very specific times, and sometimes Passenger's request queue goes above 100 and users get a 503.

How do I set a higher number of threads?

I am using Passenger and Nginx, deploying with Capistrano using the capistrano-passenger gem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/optimization/) at Phusion Passenger seems to answer your question directly, and provide some guidance for related questions.

> **Step 3: configure Passenger**
>
> **Purely single-threaded multi-process scenarios**
>
> Configure:
>
> ```
> passenger_max_pool_size <desired_app_processes>;
> passenger_min_instances <desired_app_processes>;
> passenger_pre_start to have your app started automatically at web server boot.
> ```
>
> **Multithreaded scenarios**
>
> In order to use multithreading you must use Passenger Enterprise. The
>   open source version of Passenger does not support multithreading.
>
> Configure:
>
> ```
> passenger_max_pool_size <CHOSEN_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES>;
> passenger_min_instances <CHOSEN_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES>;
> passenger_concurrency_model thread;
> passenger_thread_count <desired_app_threads_per_process>;
> passenger_pre_start to have your app started automatically at web server boot.
> If desired_app_processes is 1, then you should set passenger_spawn_method direct. By using direct spawning instead of
> ```
>
> smart spawning, Passenger will not keep a Preloader process around,
>   saving you some memory (learn more at Spawn methods). This is because
>   a Preloader process is useless when there's only 1 application
>   process.

Comment: This definitely got me in the right direction, thanks!